# read in mingw under windows does not read entire file. Why?

Tags: c++, file, mingw, binaryfiles

Using mingw under windows the following code which works under linux does not work:

```
int fh = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
const int size=100000;
int bytesRead = read(fh, buffer, size);
```

The file is bigger than 100k yet bytes read is just 232. I think this has something to do with binary files in windows?

This code with ifstream will work in windows and Linux.

```
ifstream in(filename, ios::binary);
const int size=100000;
in.read(buffer, size);
```

Is there a way to make level 2 IO calls work on windows as well?

Comment: Have you tried `O_RDONLY | O_BINARY`? I suspect that byte 232 of your binary file is something which is erroneously detected as end-of-file (in Windows). I've seen `O_BINARY` here and there but failed to find something like an "authoritative" doc.

Comment: I normally google man open, not realizing that the compatability functions aren't compatible. Where do you find the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Reading manuals is very useful technics.

[_read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/read)

> **Return Value**
>
> `_read` returns the number of bytes read, which **might be less than buffer_size** if there are fewer than buffer_size bytes left in the file, **or if the file was opened in text mode**. In text mode, each carriage return-line feed pair \r\n is replaced with a single line feed character \n. Only the single line feed character is counted in the return value. The replacement does not affect the file pointer.

[**Text and Binary Mode File I/O**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/text-and-binary-mode-file-i-o)

> File I/O operations take place in one of two translation modes, text or binary, depending on the mode in which the file is opened. Data files are usually processed in text mode.
>
> - Use the function `_set_fmode` to change the default mode for newly opened files. Use `_get_fmode` to find the current default mode. **The initial default setting is text mode (_O_TEXT)**.
> - Change the default translation mode directly by setting the global variable `_fmode` in your program. The function `_set_fmode` sets the value of this variable, but it can also be set directly.

`open(filename, O_RDONLY);` opens files in text mode in Windows by default.

`open(filename, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);` opens files in binary mode in Windows and further `read` will read all requested bytes if there's enough bytes left in the file.

Comment: I looked up the open function using man 2 open, which does not  of course show the incompatibilty. Where is the manual you are referring to?

Comment: @Dov Why do you read Linux manual page when you are programming for Windows?

Comment: Again where is the manual you are referring to? searching mingw library documentation open read ... does not turn up an answer. I always assumed that the functions were the same as linux because that is their purpose. And most are. Are you trying to provide an answer or more interested in criticizing?

Comment: I'm sorry if you are seeing critique in the advice. https://www.google.com/search?q=win32+read, the first link [read_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/read).